# Wrong string found while parsing HTML

Tags: c#, regex, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my Regular Expression for getting version number from playstore HTML content:

```
var content = responseMsg.Content == null 
                  ? null 
                  : await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var versionMatch = Regex.Match(
    content, 
    "<div[^>]*>Current Version</div><span[^>]*><div><span[^>]*>(.*?)<").Groups[1];

if (versionMatch.Success)
{
    version = versionMatch.Value.Trim();
}
```

[image]

Here I am getting this value Inside VersionMatch= "{}"

So how to get this proper version? like VersionMatch="1.9"

The html content is very large so I cut off from that html content :

```
<div class="hAyfc">
<div class="BgcNfc">Current Version</div>
<span class="htlgb">
<div class="IQ1z0d">
<span class="htlgb">1.9</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just because the string is displayed in the web browser developer tools DOM view, doesn't mean it is also this way in your actual HTML source code coming from the server.

Comment: BTW: [Using Regex to parse HTML is really bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/107625).

Comment: so can you give me a proper solution to get this version number?

Comment: @swe Please [stop adding tags to titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/133056).

Comment: What about the text between `Current Version</div>` and the `<span>` where the version number is in? Your regex does not match this.

Comment: Try removing \r\n before parsing it, you have "div><span" where in fact you have div>\r\n<span>

Comment: This regex was working fine,but recently I noticed that it not working.

Comment: It will be better if you submit the HTML by "Right click >> view source" than from inspect. in order to see the exact HTML how it looks like.

Comment: I update my code.please see this

Comment: @UweKeim I did not add a tag to the title. I corrected a typo and added the "regex"-tag to the taglist. Why do you think i did? - aaahh. reviewing the history makes it clear: it seems as if i edited the title. I did accidentally. I think it was because of an concurrent edit, because i did in fact not change it... I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip over the intermediate text between `Current Version</div>` and the `<span>` where the version number is in, you can use a (non-greedy) `.*?`. The dot will also match `\r\n`, if `RegexOptions.Singleline` is given. To get the correct span, specify its content as "digits and dots" (`[\d\.]+`) instead of "anything" (`.*?`)

```
var content = @"<div class=""hAyfc"">
<div class=""BgcNfc"">Current Version</div>
<span class=""htlgb"">
<div class=""IQ1z0d"">
<span class=""htlgb"">1.9</span>
</div>";

var versionMatch = Regex.Match(
    content, 
    @"<div[^>]*>Current Version</div>.*?<span[^>]*>([\d\.]+)<", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1];
```

versionMatch.Value is then "1.9"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) with [Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack/) so you can basically do something like this:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var html = web.Load(uri);
var documentNode = html.DocumentNode;
var version = documentNode.QuerySelector(".htlgb").InnerHtml;
```

And you don't have to worry about the regex

Comment: Its throwing null reference exception.